# error after compiling .py to .exe

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

[when I compile a program from .py into .exe and open .exe, this error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmlPK.jpg)

when I compile a program from .py into .exe and open .exe, this error appears

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
name = "Diophantine equantion",
version = "1.0",
description = "Diophantine equantion",
executables = [Executable("Diofant.py", base='Win32GUI')]
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `options = {'build_exe': {'includes': ['numpy.core._methods']}}` to your setup.

Comment: Please write the full code, because it produces an error on the command line

Comment: Umm... you probably misses a comma at the end.